# SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe: How to resubmit analysis report?

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I'm working on SonarQube setup which should handle a C# project with 50+k source files.
I have managed to tune SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe parameters so it doesn't crash with OOM errors during analysis anymore (I have increased heap and excluded XML files from analysis). The analysis completes successfully and the scanner successfully submits on server.

Now I'm getting OOM errors on server side (in a background task). I'm about to tune sonar.ce.javaOpts and sonar.search.javaOpts.

How can I resubmit the analysis report from the client to the SQ server without rerunning analysis? The analysis takes 14 hours, and I would like to avoid to wait for it again.

Is it possible to restart the failed background task after restart of SQ server with the new heap parameters?

My software:
sonar-scanner-msbuild-3.0.0.629
sonarqube-6.4

Comment: I'm not sure of this, but perhaps if you rerun just the end step of the scanner for msbuild (no begin step and no build), it might re-upload the last report.

Answer (score 0):

The scanner submits the report via a web service (in the `web` process). The web service stores the report in the `ce_task` database table. The compute engine (`ce` process) then reads this table, processes the report, and marks it as done.

My ideas, at your own risk, **only for test instances**!

If you had a database snapshot of the state, where the processing of the report is not yet done, it would probably start the processing automatically.

You could also try to set the state to not done, manually in the database.